# Angularjs error when trying to read title from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS along with Node.js and I'm trying to read title from a specific url
I have something like this:

```
App.config(function($httpProvider) {
      //Enable cross domain calls
      $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

      //Remove the header used to identify ajax call  that would prevent CORS from working
      delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  });
```

And I try to read urls title with:

```
$http({ url:$scope.url,method:"POST", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-       urlencoded'}}).success(function(data){

       console.log(data);
     });
```

But I get NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed **and/or** Cross-Origin Request Blocked:....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what your client-side code is, you'll need to enable CORS on the server side to allow Cross-Origin requests.

Comment: so it has nothing to do with AngularJS?